# Mircosoft Graph API Authentication token by using v2.0 and v1.0

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

```
$LoginUrl = "https://login.microsoft.com"
```

$Tenantname = "xxxx"

```
$Body = @ {
    client_id = "xxxx"
    client_secret = "xxxx"
    resource  = "https://graph.microsoft.com"
    grant_type = "client_credentials"
}

$oauth = Invoke-RestMethod -Method Post -Uri $LoginUrl/$Tenantname/oauth2/v2.0/token -Body $Body
```

Above is my Authentication to get token for Graph API, application registration has been done. Below error when I use the v2.0 for token.

```
Invoke-RestMethod:    {"error":"invalid_request","error_description":"AADSTS901002: The 'resource' request parameter is not supported" ......}
```

But, I can get it run when I used below, that I searched from website.
I got confused where is wrong, and why below v1.0 is working.

```
$oauth = Invoke-RestMethod -Method Post -Uri     $LoginUrl/$Tenantname/oauth2/token?api-version=1.0 -Body $Body
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As documented [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/auth-v2-service), you don't need the resource-parameter (you can read that from the error message) for v2-auth. But what you are missing and is required according to the docu:

---

`scope`
**Required**
The value passed for the scope parameter in this request should be the resource identifier (Application ID URI) of the resource you want, affixed with the .default suffix. For Microsoft Graph, the value is https://graph.microsoft.com/.default. This value informs the Microsoft identity platform endpoint that of all the application permissions you have configured for your app, it should issue a token for the ones associated with the resource you want to use.

---